# Disable Upgrade to El Capitan

Tags: macos, upgrade

I have Maverick and the option to Upgrade to OS X El Capitan pops up.
I don't want to do this. Ever.
How do I disable this notification?

Comment: What's wrong with El Capitan? I runs amazing well on my ancient 2009 MacBook Pro.

Comment: I have no personal experience with this, but there may be 32 bit vs 64 bit issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **System Preferences** go to **App Store** and disable **Automatically check for updates.**

[image]